# How does Dropbox LAN Sync work?

Tags: sync, lan, dropbox

I have installed Dropbox on 2 Ubuntu machines and enabled LAN sync. I was curious how does one Dropbox instance detect  another.

Comment: Probably a hello, handshake, and a package.  Just like your UPS driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a UDP broadcast packet is sent over the LAN.

I found these links to support:

http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=12180

> "we've experimented with various service discovery protocols, both
>   standardized and our own. right now we're using UDP broadcast, but
>   we're testing a few different ideas to see what'll work best for most
>   people. the server is only involved in lansync negotiation to enforce
>   our security model."

http://p0stmaster.blogspot.com/2011/01/dropbox-lan-sync.html

> For example, if I look at a packet capture for my LAN I see "[source
>   IP] 255.255.255.255 DB-LSP-Dropbox LAN Sync Discovery Protocol" every
>   few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

It does by sending UDP packets every 30 seconds. Check the post below ...

[Dropbox LAN Sync Protocol](http://web.archive.org/web/20120502064502/http://geeklogs.posterous.com/dropbox-lan-sync-protocol) (archived)

Comment: The link you gave is dead.